Laravel + InertiaJs + ReactJs is not updating users cache
I do changes and are not reflected in users devices and I think is cache issue. run npm run production before deploying but nothing. The only way to see the changes in the site is my pressing F5. I will give you a list of the things I try without success:

run commands in server terminal:
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear

.htaccess:
 
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
 
 
     
         Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
         Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     
 
 
     ExpiresActive On
     ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 second"
     ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 second"
 

Adding params in app.blade.php to keep it updated:

adding version in webpack.mix.js:


const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .react()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css')
    .version();


Now I did a big update and most of screens are completly white and only F5 will solve it, but cant go asking to users to do that.
What else can I try?

I just randomly came across this but have you looked into this? https://inertiajs.com/asset-versioning#cache-busting
